# Getting the value of an XML Element that also has attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm using the .NET XmlSerializer class to deserialize some XML document. In that document, I have an element that looks like that:

```
<MyElement attr1="xxx" attr2="yyy">VALUE</MyElement>
```

This is a part of a bigger XML. I need to deserialize this string into an object, so I wrote:

```
public class MyElement
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attr1")]
    public string attr1 { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "attr2")]
    public string attr2  { get; set; }

    [??????????????]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

And I can't figure out what to put instead of the question marks in order to get the value of the element into the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[XmlTextAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute.aspx):

> By default, the XmlSerializer serializes a class member as an XML element. However, if you apply the XmlTextAttribute to a member, the XmlSerializer translates its value into XML text. This means that the value is encoded into the content of an XML element.

```
[XmlText]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `XmlTextAttribute` does not work, you could use the [XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx)

```
[XmlElement( DataType = "string", ElementName = "value" )]
public string value { get; set; }
```